# android studio encoding can't change single encoding to UTF-8

Tags: android, android-studio

See the pics
**In setting**
[image: in setting]

**In editor**
[image: in editor]

**In notepad ++, it can show the chinese text, the file encoding is UTF-8**
[image: in notepad ++, it can show the chinese text, the file encoding is UTF-8]

**In the app, it is a strange characters**
[image: In the app, it is a strange characters]

**In gradle script, i've added:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.prgguru.example"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
        productFlavors {
        }
        compileOptions {
            encoding "UTF-8"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
        compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    }
```

Anyone knows how to fix the encoding problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert String to utf-8

```
URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: before upgrade gradle and using new android studio, i don't need code to change encoding. The actually i did is using new android studio to open a old project.

Comment: but did you try this work or not? I believe android studio can backward support the previous version, so if your text can display, then should be fine